# CPU clock speed goes down when I enable my integrated graphics GPU

Tags: laptop, cpu, gpu, cpu-speed

I know that there are many reasons and fixes for those reasons for what is happening to my laptop; an old one too from 2013.

Everytime: I enable my integrated graphics my CPU clock speed fluctuates and goes from 3.1hz to 2-0.8hz.

I have a program called throttle stop that I use. On it there is a limit tracker and it tracks the things throttling/limiting my laptop. I have a throttle/limit on it that is called edp current that is on mostly all the time. It shows up for my CPU and a thing called ring that happens when my integrated graphics are off, but when they are on then I get that limit on my GPU.

When I get the limit on my gpu is when my clock speeds fluctuate and also my power draw decreases from 15-20 to 8-13. I have done a lot of stuff to try to fix it but I can not.

So my bandaid solution is to enable my integrated graphics when I launch a game and to disable to play it because my dedicated graphics does not support OpenGL it works but for games like Payday 2 I have to keep it enabled.

TL;DR: My GPU gets throttled every time I enable my integrated graphics and makes my cpu clock speeds fluctuate.

---

**Edit**: I did a new better bandaid fix. It stops my computer from throttling but it makes my resolution locked at 1600x900.

What I did is I went into device manager and changed my integrated graphics driver from it's driver to a display adapter it enables the perk of having my integrated graphics on and I can now play games with OpenGL and not get throttled but I can not change my resolution because my dedicated graphics is weird and won't let me change my resolution.

So I still need a fix and cleaning my computer did not work

Comment: Have you cleaned the inside of the laptop out of the dust bunnies?

Comment: Yep but I will do it again